# Byte separator for MOV command in assembly (masm)

Tags: assembly, masm

What if in a MOV command you want to write the bytes as separate numbers, one for each byte, instead of one single number? What separator would you then use between the bytes?

Also, what byte separator can be used in macro calls, as comma is already occupied as a parameter separator?

As an example, the following is what I am looking for, if ; would be used as separator:

```
MOV ax, 25h;'D'
```

IN above example, the first byte is written as a hexadecimal number, the second one is written as a string.

```
MOV edx, 25h;'A';254;'L'
```

In the above example, the first byte is written as a hexadecimal number, the second and fourth one as a string, and the third as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Seperator? "the" bytes? Which bytes? "as seperate numbers"? What numbers?

Comment: Please provide a code example that illustrates what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any separator between the bytes. Write both numbers (byte) in hexadecimal form.

First number 23  = 17h
Second number 51 = 33h

Then use a single `mov` to use both bytes together:

```
mov ax, 3317h
```

EDIT

Change

```
MOV edx, 25h;'A';254;'L'
```

into

```
mov edx, 25h + ('A' << 8) + (254 << 16) + ('L' << 24)
```

Comment: What if you want to write one byte as a number and the next as a string? Can you write `MOV ax, 33h'L'` ?

Comment: That would depend on what the assembler allows as an expression. Try the following: `mov ax, 'L' * 256 + 33h`